# .NET - EF service unit test vs integration test

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a question about the difference between a unit test and an integration test. I have an API in .NET and I have an Infrastructure layer where for example I delete data in the database. I write this data using DbContext - Entity framework. But the DbContext is quite easy to mock using InMemoryDbContext.

And this is where my question comes in. Is this a unit test or an integration test? Assuming I connect directly to a db it's integration for me, but in this case?

This method i want test.

```
public MyDbContext _context;

public void Delete(int id)
{
    _cotnext.Delete(id);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `and I use clean architecture` this means absolutely nothing, nor does it have anything to do with using multiple layers. Multi-layer architectures existed for more than 10 years (closer to 20) before some authors coined the term "clean architecture" to refer to their books

Comment: The question itself isn't meaningful either - the code you posted isn't a test in the first place. It's just an alias for a DbContext method. It *could* point to antipatterns like CRUD classes over Unit-of-Work, but there's just nothing more than a call to `DbContext.Delete` here. This won't even modify the database until you commint the Unit-of-Work/DbContext with SaveChanges

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry i tried change my question. I hope now its cleaner.

Comment: No, it's not. Whether it's a unit test or not depends on how you use that method. You *can* use a normal test database to test data access code, and still have a unit test, because you're only testing that data access code. If that's your real code, it does look like you use the CRUD-over-Unit-of-Work antipattern though. That's a real, very serious problem.

Comment: Still: what you show is not a test. The answers is still: neither.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a unit test or an integration test?

Does it matter?

Unit tests should test some "unit", but that unit can be of arbitrary size. It may be a class, but it might as well be the "storage system". And you often have multiple levels of "units", everything from individual methods, up to complete programs. Debating what is a unit and what are integration between units might not be productive.

"Unit tests" are in some cases used to mean all automated tests, so if you want to categorize your tests, unit vs integration might not be the best option. A potentially better ways is to categorize by runtime. Tests tests that take seconds or minutes can be useful to run separately from tests that take milliseconds.

For a database you would typically test most functions with a in-memory mock of the database. But it is certainly also useful to test queries with a real database to ensure that they actually work correctly. We are calling the later "integration tests", but we might as well have called it "database tests" or "slow tests". The important thing is that the meanings are clear within your team.

Answer (score 0):

There is considerable debate on what constitutes a unit test, so there is an element of 'what works for you.’

At it's purest, though, unit tests are philosophically testing that unit and that unit alone. If you are involving a data store, then you are testing the interaction between 2 components, and we could argue this stray into integration testing. Some will argue, though, that in-memory databases are, in themselves, mocks.

One thing is to consider also is that unit tests should be as fast as possible. This is to reduce the speed of iteration for the Red-Green-Refactor TDD development cycle, and to quicken the feedback loop of tests during development. Fast unit tests also speed up tools like mutation testing which run unit tests many times over.

Writing to a database, however you do it, will involve interacting with some sort of storage, and this will come at a performance costs. Entity framework has an in-memory DB that you can use in your unit tests, which makes this storage interaction faster, but it's still not as fast as calling out to mocked class methods.